# Regenerate private key from password

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

Is it possible to recreate a private key for an encrypted string by using the same information how it was created?

For example, I create a public and private key from a password and encrypt something with the public key. Later I don’t have the private key and want to create it by using the same password again. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, though I'm not aware of any library that makes it easy to do this. It's also almost always a bad idea -- there are almost always better ways to accomplish your goal, whatever that may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the algorithms, however, for the vast majority of them, the answer is no: Generally, a key pair is made by using random a lot of random information, and then your password is used to encrypt the private key. (yes, it's encryption in encryption).

For example, an RSA key pair or a diffie-hellman keypair both involve random input to generate these.